# SQL: adding "not in" slows the SQL command

Tags: sql-server, join

Adding "not in" statement to my SQL command makes the whole thing extremely slow. Any suggestion on how to get around this would be greatly appreciated!

```
select distinct 
    d.fiscal_year,d.calendar_year,d.month_num
from vw_ePCR_eMeds_tickets v
    inner join incident_date_dim d on v.ticketdos=d.inci_date
    left join vw_all_incidents i on i.CADIncidentNumber=v.incident_num
where TicketDOS between  '12/01/2017' and '05/31/2018'
    and [transportedstatus] = 'transported'
    and i.call_type_id  not in (
        select call_type_id
        from DW_EMS_Elite.dbo.MCFRS_EMS_BillingExclude 
    )
```

Comment: It's impossible to answer questions about performance without the query, table schema, indexes and at least an indication of data sizes, and *the execution plan*. `NOT IN` isn't slow. The server *doesn't* execute the query as-is either. It compiles an execution plan based on indexes, data statistics and the query itself. The *same* query can have a very different execution plan if an index is missing. This means the execution plan is the most important piece of information after the query itself

Comment: Is the `call_type_id` column covered by an index in all tables? If not, the query will be slow.

Comment: Just curious.  How many elements appear in the not in ( ... )

Comment: @John Cappelletti - 9 total.

Comment: BTW `TicketDOS between  '12/01/2017' and '05/31/2018'` almost guarantees problems *unless* `TicketDOS` is a `date` and the locale is `en-US`. This date *literal* only works in the US. The unambiguous date literal form is `YYYYMMDD`. If `TicketDOS` is a string, the query will perform an alphanumeric comparison with the most imporant digits coming last.

Comment: Nominal, OK that would not be a factor.  I'm leaning towards Kanavos

Comment: For a test, replace it with: `and not exists (
  select 1 
  from DW_EMS_Elite.dbo.MCFRS_EMS_BillingExclude 
  where call_type_id = i.call_type_id
)`. Sometimes exists or not exists performs better.

Comment: @forpas it shouldn't. That's one of the oldest heuristics. The query optimizer will generate the same execution plan for both. Without the execution plan everything is speculation. The existence or not of an index on the `call_type_id` columns is *far* more important.

Comment: @forpas the content of the views is also important. Where does `vw_all_incidents.call_type_id` come from? We don't really know what the query looks like right now. That view could hide a `max(someID) as call_type_id` which means the query *has* to calculate all results for the view before starting to filter by `MCFRS_EMS_BillingExclude`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos it shouldn't, but also it shouldn't make such a big difference a scan on a 9 items list, but it does (according to the OP)

Comment: if you think "Not In " Slow down your performance then user Left join on DW_EMS_Elite.dbo.MCFRS_EMS_BillingExclude rather than "Not In".

Comment: @forpas you assume that's what's slowing things down. it could be the *views* that have to calculate 1M result rows when only 9 rows would match

Comment: @HardikPatel it shouldn't matter. The *execution plan* will probably be the same. We *don't* know what the execution plan is right now, so everything is just random guesses

Comment: @KenshinH post the SQL for the views too and post the *execution plan*. It's impossible to help when the important information is missing

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - thanks for the information. Unfortunately, I am not in a position to disclose what you're asking, and I have to work with what I provided...

Comment: @KenshinH then you can't get any help, apart from the suggestion to add more indexes.

Comment: @KenshinH Check the execution plan yourself and identify the expensive operations and "fat" lines to find out candidates for optimization. Check for warning icons. Investigate any large `Table Scan` operations and try to add indexes or modify the **views** so these change to seeks.

Comment: @KenshinH check [Basic SQL Server Performance Troubleshooting For Developers](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/performance/basic-sql-server-performance-troubleshooting-for-developers/)

Answer (score 0):

Just give it a try

```
with cte as (
    select call_type_id from DW_EMS_Elite.dbo.MCFRS_EMS_BillingExclude
)
select distinct 
    d.fiscal_year,
    d.calendar_year,
    d.month_num
from
    vw_ePCR_eMeds_tickets       as v
    join incident_date_dim      as d on ( v.ticketdos=d.inci_date )
    left join vw_all_incidents  as i on ( i.CADIncidentNumber=v.incident_num )
    left join cte               as c on ( c.call_type_id = i.call_type_id )
where 
    ( ( '20171201'<= TicketDOS ) and ( TicketDOS < '20180601' ) )
    and ( [transportedstatus] = 'transported' )
    and ( c.call_type_id is null )
```

Comment: Thanks, but it is still way too slow.

Comment: Why would this behave any differently? Using a CTE here is no different than a `LEFT JOIN MCFRS_EMS_BillingExclude`.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos This is true.